# kotlin, how to return a generic type member variable

Tags: generics, kotlin

Got error when returning a member variable of generic type  (on Android, not sure if it makes any difference)

```
private var mData: T? = null
override fun <T> getJsonPOJO(): T? {
    return mData
}
```

`Type mismatch: inferred type is T#2 (type parameter of RemoteData)? but T#1 (type parameter of RemoteData.getJsonPOJO)? was expected`

here is the code, the function is returning a generic type:

```
interface IRemoteData {
    fun isSuccess() : Boolean
    fun <T> getJsonPOJO() : T?
    fun getCode() : Int
    fun getMessage() : String
}


class RemoteData<T>(response: Response<ResponseBody>, pojoClassType: Class<T>) : IRemoteData {

    private val mIsSuccess: Boolean = response.isSuccessful
    private val mCode: Int = response.code()
    private val mMessage : String = response.message() ?: ""

    private var mData: T? = null
    init {
        val jsonString: String? = response.body()?.string() ?: ""
        mData = if (jsonString != null) Gson().fromJson(jsonString, pojoClassType) else null
    }

    override fun isSuccess(): Boolean {
        return mIsSuccess
    }

    override fun <T> getJsonPOJO(): T? {
        return mData  //<=== compile error here
    }

    override fun getCode(): Int {
        return mCode
    }

    override fun getMessage(): String {
        return mMessage
    }

}
```

any suggestion is much appreciated!

tried just to return the passed in T, it still gets same error:

```
class RemoteData<T>(response: Response<ResponseBody>, pojoClassType: Class<T>, testData: T) : IRemoteData {
......
    private var mData: T? = testData
......
    override fun <T> getJsonPOJO(): T? {
        return mData  //<=== same compiler error
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the leading `<T>`.

Comment: after remove the leading<T> from the class RemoteData<T> (error: unresovled T) or fun <T> getJsonPOJO() (same old error),  it still got compiler error error.

Comment: The <T> declaration in your class is different than the <T> declaration in your method. ie, class <T> != method <T>

Comment: As @nicholas.hauschild says, you need to bind the `T` to both the interface and the class declaration: `interface IRemoteData<T> {...}` and then `class RemoteData<T> ... : IRemoteData<T> { ... }`

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild, could you please explain why the same T is not the same? it has "testData: T" passed in and just return that 'testData"  still get error.  thanks!

Comment: `T` is not special and is not shared unless you explicitly share it. See my comment above.

Comment: I added <T> in both interface IRemoteData<T>,   and class RemoteData<T>(response: Response<ResponseBody>, pojoClassType: Class<T>, d: T) : IRemoteData<T>  {},  still same error.   I do want the same type 'T' in everywhere in this class.

Comment: I'll write an answer once I get home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
interface IRemoteData<T> {
    fun isSuccess() : Boolean
    fun getJsonPOJO() : T?
    fun getCode() : Int
    fun getMessage() : String
}


class RemoteData<T>(response: Response<ResponseBody>, pojoClassType: Class<T>) : IRemoteData<T> {

    private var mData: T? = null
    override fun getJsonPOJO(): T? {
        return mData
    }

}
```

The `T` will be replaced everywhere, so just imagine if it was `String` (I find it simpler when playing around with generic types).
You'd have:

```
interface IRemoteData<String> {
  fun getJsonPOJO(): String?
}

class RemoteData<String>(...): IRemoteData<String> {
  private var mData: String? = null
  override fun getJsonPOJO(): String? {
    return mData
  }
}
```

That's it !

Comment: thank you guys,  removing the leading<T> from  override fun <T> getJsonPOJO():   is what needed.    now another error:

val remoteData = RemoteData(response, POJOClazz::class.java)

onRemoteDataReady(remoteData)
//<===  got Type mismatch: inferred type is RemoteData<out Class<T>> but IRemoteData<T>? was expected

the function is with data: T?
fun onRemoteDataReady(data :T?)

Comment: Glad to hear that fixed your issue. However I'm not sure I understand what your second problem is. Would you happen to have more code to share, maybe a pastebin? Because from this, I can't know where you defined `onRemoteDataReady()` nor where/how you call it

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to create a class with one type argument which extends an interface with one type argument. First, add the generic type to your interface signature.

```
interface IRemoteData<T>
```

It may be helpful to look at the concrete class's type argument as a different letter.

```
class RemoteData<E>
```

Notice if all RemoteData instances used `Int` rather than a generic type, you would drop the `<E>` type and simply extend IRemoteData with `Int` as the type parameter.

```
class RemoteData : IRemoteData<Int>
```

However, what you're looking for is to pass the generic type provided to RemoteData directly to IRemoteData.

```
class RemoteData<E> : IRemoteData<E>
```

So, when you instantiate a RemoteData as `RemoteData<Int>` the return type of `IRemoteData::getJsonPojo()` will be `Int`.

All together:

```
interface IRemoteData<T> {
    fun getJsonPojo(): T
}

class RemoteData<E> : IRemoteData<E> {

    override fun getJsonPojo(): E {
        // return something type E
    }
}

// elsewhere
val data = RemoteData<Int>()
val x: Int = data.getJsonPojo()
```