# how to pass a generic typed data to a function taking the generic type

Tags: generics, kotlin

got one question resolved in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949724/kotlin-how-to-return-a-generic-type-member-variable/49950036#49950036)

```
interface IRemoteData<T> {
    fun getJsonPOJO() : T?
}

class RemoteData<T>(response: Response<ResponseBody>, pojoClassType: Class<T>) : IRemoteData<T> {

    private var mData: T? = null
    override fun getJsonPOJO(): T? {
        return mData
    }
}
```

now after created a RemoteData instance

```
val remoteData = RemoteData(response, POJOClazz::class.java)
```

get another error when passing this remoteData to a function which takes a generic type as well

```
handler.onRemoteDataReady(remoteData)
//<===  got Type mismatch: inferred type is RemoteData<out Class<T>> but IRemoteData<T>? was expected
```

the function is defined with in a interface taking d: T?

```
interface IHandler<T> {   
    fun onRemoteDataReady(data :T?)
}
```

the handler instance:

```
class ResponseHandler(val action: Action) : BaseHandler(action), IHandler<IRemoteData> {
    init {
        mAction?.preAction(this)
    }
    override fun onRemoteDataReady(data: IRemoteData?) {
        val responseRecieved = data?.getJsonPOJO()
        .......
   }
}
```

Comment: is onRemoteDataReady defined within the same scope as RemoteData?

Comment: no, but in another interface, I updated the question

Comment: How is `handler` defined?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I update the question, thanks!

Comment: Actually `class ResponseHandler(val action: Action) : BaseHandler(action), IHandler<IRemoteData>` should already fail to compile because of missing type argument for `IRemoteData<T>`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the interface `IRemoteData` needs a generic type.

Here's the working example:

```
interface IHandler<T> {
    fun onRemoteDataReady(data :T?)
}

class ResponseHandler<T>(val action: Action) : BaseHandler(action), IHandler<IRemoteData<T>> {

    override fun onRemoteDataReady(data: IRemoteData<T>?) {
        val responseReceived = data?.getJsonPOJO()
    }
}
```

And it's usage:

```
val remoteData = RemoteData(response, POJOClazz::class.java)
val handler = ResponseHandler<POJOClazz::class.java>(action)
handler.onRemoteDataReady(remoteData)
```

Remember from the previous answer, your interface `IRemoteData` needs a type. So when you declare the `ResponseHandler` class, you need to specify the type as well. A `ResponseHandler<String>` will implement `IRemoteData<String>`.

Comment: thanks, but with your change still got: "Type mismatch: inferred type is RemoteData<out Class<T>> but IRemoteData<T>? was expected",  I guess the instantiated   val remoteData = RemoteData(response, POJOClazz::class.java)    is not considered to  be type of required IRemoteData<T>