# Kotlin: Type mismatch between interface generic type T and parameter object type T

Tags: generics, kotlin

As an exercise to understand ReactiveX better I'm trying to implement the very basics of ReactiveX in Kotlin (guided by the RxJs example [here](https://youtu.be/uQ1zhJHclvs)). 
I think the idea behind what I currently get is correct, but I'm stuck with one implementation detail that I can't get my head around.

This is the *Observer* interface:

```
interface Observer<T> {

    fun next(data: T)

    fun error(e: Throwable)

    fun complete()
}
```

This is the *Observable* Interface:

```
interface Observable<T> {
    fun subscribe(observer: Observer<T>)

    fun <T, R> map(transformer: (input: T) -> R): Observable<R> {
        val inputObservable = this
        val outputObservable = object : Observable<R> {
            override fun subscribe(outputObserver: Observer<R>) {
                inputObservable.subscribe(object : Observer<T> {
                    override fun next(data: T) {
                        val y = transformer(data)
                        outputObserver.next(y)
                    }

                    override fun error(e: Throwable) {
                        outputObserver.error(e)
                    }

                    override fun complete() {
                        outputObserver.complete()
                    }
                })
            }

        }
        return outputObservable
    }
}
```

The error I have is in the following line:

inputObservable.subscribe(**object : Observer** {

I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Observable<T#2 (type parameter of observable.Observable)> but Observable<T#1 (type parameter of observable.Observable.map)> was expected
```

I think my problem is very similar to that in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949724/kotlin-how-to-return-a-generic-type-member-variable). If I am correct the type T from the Observable interface is not linked to the type T of the Observer (which results in T#1 and T#2).  In that question the solution is to use the T in both the Interface and class declaration but I don't see how I can define the type of the *object*.

Is my reasoning correct? How can I link these two T's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `map()` method should have a single generic parameter: `R`. It's part of an interface that is *already* generic, and already has a generic type `T`. So making it generic on `T` too introduces *another* generic type `T` that hides the interface's generic type `T`.

TL;DR:

```
fun <T, R> map(transformer: (input: T) -> R): Observable<R> {
```

should be

```
fun <R> map(transformer: (input: T) -> R): Observable<R> {
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I understand now, and your solution did indeed fix the issue.